# Adding and subtracting data from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, sumifs

I have an Excel sheet in Microsoft Excel 2007 in which there are entries for four items (A, B, C, D ) not in the specific order and on regular basis each any of the above four items can be added with quantity. This is basically called as **INWARD**. 
Now in **outward**, I have a similar process happening in a non sequential manner.

There is a third sheet called as MASter in which each item (A, B, C, D) has a final stock available which is basically `=(inward-outward)`. I want to create a system in which if on any subsequent dates any of the four items are added to inward the stock list should get updated by adding the qty. and the moment there is any outward of the same material the same should get deducted.

How should I do the above?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned your layout, but the principle below should suit:

[image: SO14232642 example]

with

```
=SUMIFS(INWARD!B:B,INWARD!A:A,A1)-SUMIFS(outward!B:B,outward!A:A,A1)
```

in B1 of MASter and copied down.